# JupyterLab configuration file - editing jupyter_notebook_config.py has no effect

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm using JupyterLab version 1.2.3

I have generated a `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file by running `jupyter-lab --generate-config`.

At the bottom of the file, I have added the line `c.InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"`.

However, when I run `jupyter lab`, the notebook still behaves as if the default value for `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity` were set.

Is any other step required to make the configuration file active? Or how can I "debug" to better understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You must generate a config file in IPython with the command:

```
$ ipython profile create
```

the created file would be `ipython_kernel_config.py`
On this file, you must make the changes indicated